# Can visitors enter the inner caldera of the double volcano island Aogashima, Japan?

Tags: japan, islands, volcanoes

[Aogashima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aogashima) is one of the Izu island of Japan that isn't very famous for some reason, but definitely should be.

The whole island is basically a volcano rising steeply up out of the sea. Within the caldera of the volcano is a second smaller volcano with its own second caldera!

The island has a population of about 200 living in the village inside the large crater.

But I can't find a lot of information about tourism there. [Wikivoyage has a brief article.](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Aogashima) What I can't find is whether it's possible/safe to visit the inner crater/caldera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, people even [camp there](http://www.spoon-tamago.com/2014/01/31/wanderlust-tokyos-volcanic-crater-island-aogashima/) specially for the starlight. These images are by the way the 4th hit on Google search for "aogashima".

[This tiny map](http://www.vill.aogashima.tokyo.jp/images/tourism/map01.jpg) which somehow disappeared from the [official website](http://www.vill.aogashima.tokyo.jp/tourism/map.html) of Aogashima also indicates where the path is to reach the center.